# Group by linq query result exception issue

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group by my results and the check null but it throwing error on `.Any()` or `.Count()` and `someDocs` is in memory collection

```
var devices = someDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Devices).GroupBy(x => x.type);

if (devices != null && devices.Count()>0) // Exception : Object not set to instance of Object 
{
   //my code 
}
```

How can I check that grouped result is null?

Answer (score 0):

Check if someDocs is not not, before doing a linq query over it.

Also check this

```
GroupBy(x => x.type!= null )
```

Answer (score 0):

to Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

```
if (devices != null && devices.Any() ) 
{

}
```

Comment: I used this but but got same exception

Comment: is it! but how! can you please add full stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps getting the exception because `someDocs` is null?
In the code that you posted, at first sight, this is the only place that this exception could be thrown.

Try this:

```
if(someDocs == null){
 someDocs = new List<TypeOfSomeDocsElement>();
}
var devices = someDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Devices).GroupBy(x => x.type);

if (devices != null && devices.Count()>0) // Exception : Object not set to instance of Object 
{
   //my code 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var devices = someDocs.SelectMany(x => x.Devices)
                      .Where(x.type!=null)
                      .GroupBy(x => x.type);
```